# In Google Tag Manager, what to set user-defined variables for ecommerce items?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

If I'm using [GTM to track ecommerce purchases](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ecommerce-ga4#measure_purchases), what do I set the data layer variable in GTM for the purchased items' properties? Take this, for example:

```js
dataLayer.push({
  event: "purchase",
  ecommerce: {
      transaction_id: "T12345",
      affiliation: "Online Store",
      value: "59.89",
      tax: "4.90",
      shipping: "5.99",
      currency: "EUR",
      coupon: "SUMMER_SALE",
      items: [{
        item_name: "Triblend Android T-Shirt",
        item_id: "12345",
        price: "15.25",
        item_brand: "Google",
        item_category: "Apparel",
        item_variant: "Gray",
        quantity: 1
      }, {
        item_name: "Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt",
        item_id: "67890",
        price: 33.75,
        item_brand: "Google",
        item_category: "Apparel",
        item_variant: "Black",
        quantity: 1
      }]
  }
});
```

If I want to track `item_brand` then do I just create a variable `ecommerce.items.item_brand`? Even though `items` is an array?

Comment: There is more than one item brand. You need to specify if you want the brand for some specific item, or a list of all breands.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at GA4 tracking.
Make sure you're really using GA4. Here is the syntax for UA: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases

I'm noting it because GA4 is still under development and has very limited capabs comparing to UA.

Take a look at this article here: https://marketlytics.com/blog/pull-ecommerce-data-from-datalayer-gtm/ it indicates how you can pull the data through the DLV vars in GTM.

Surely, you can always pull the data using a custom javascript variable like so:

```js
function(){
  return dataLayer.filter(function(obj){return obj.event === "purchase"})[0].ecommerce.items;
}
```

It will return the items array though. You probably wanna set up the logic of getting the brand. Not sure what item you want to grab the brand of though, but you have a freedom to do whatever starting from here.

Answer (score 0):

There is an an array in items. Rewrite your statement as such:

**ecommerce.items.0.item_brand**

Note GTM does not accept [] notation, only dot!